# PrimeNG - Column Toggler - Seleção de determinadas colunas

Tags: angular

Olás!

Estou usando a funcionalidade de seleção de colunas do DataTable do PrimeNG. Dentre as 12 opções de colunas que tenho, gostaria que apenas 4 viessem selecionadas. Porém todas já vem selecionadas por padrão. Como realizar esse controle? Já dei uma olhada nas opções do componente MultiSelect usando para a funcionalidade de seleção de colunas no DataTable, mas ainda não encontrei uma forma.

Desde já agradeço.